# Code Analysis Tool for PowerBuilder

Tags: code-analysis, powerbuilder, static-code-analysis

Is anyone familiar with a code analysis tool along the lines of NDepend or JDepend for Powerbuilder?

I'm looking for something that can analyse dependencies and metrics such as SLOC, Cyclomatic Complexity etc. for a large, legacy Powerbuilder application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code analysis tool I know for PB is [Visual Expert](http://www.visual-expert.com/EN/powerbuilder-code-pb/function-source-analysis-documentation-impact.php). I've given it a look some time ago but have never actually used it, so I can't say if it does what the other tools you mention do.

Comment: Took a look and it does a good job of working out dependencies and unused code but not sloc or cc

Comment: There's an extension you have to enable to do SLOC. It gives you Source Lines, # Instructions, Commented Lines.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Expert is great.  PBL Peeper can do these tasks as well, and it's free...  :)

Comment: Welcome aboard, Paul. Good to see another true PB expert around!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Expert is good, but has some flaws. I tried it to analyze our server side code(EA Server) and found some issues. It's impact analysis feature is good to document a Dependency/Calling Hierarchy in the PB code.

I also tried, [PB code analyzer]:http://www.ecocion.com/pbca-powerbuilder-code-analyzer and it does a good job of documenting PB code.

I am not sure, if they do the metrics you are looking for. I found below links, googling(I didn't try these myself):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID.571F6E84.1EE2.4F68.80C7.B1DC863536CB%2FGUID-E418791C-B249-434D-BD5A-A2B570F9FA31.html

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this tool called CAST
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST_Application_Intelligence_Platform

Answer (score 0):

None of the other alleged metrics do any better than SLOC, and some are anti-predictive. Just run `wc -l` over your source files.

Comment: Or as I used to say to a guy I was mentoring: "All of your problems are in code. Your problem is you have too much code". Then I'd delete 80% of what he'd written and the program would work correctly.